Can we use AZCopy to transfer files from Autodesk construction Cloud to Azure Storage?
I am developing an application where I need to copy file from Autodesk Construction Cloud to Azure Storage, Do AZCopy support it?
Below is Autodesk Construction Cloud API endpoint, I am getting oAuth Token and passing it with request where I am reading folder contents
      var contentsEndpoint = $"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{projectId}/folders/{folderID}/contents";
    
      var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, contentsEndpoint);

      request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

  var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

  var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(responseString);
  JArray array2 = (JArray)jsonObject["data"];

  foreach (var item in array2)
  {
      if (item["type"].ToString() == "items" && item["attributes"]["displayName"].ToString() == "signature.jpg")
      {
          //return file is present
      }
  }

We want to use AZ Copy to move it to Azure Storage. I knew that we can do it from on-premise to Azure Storage or from one account to another account. But will it work with ACC?

Provide what you have tried and give detailed explanation, so community can help you

Can you add more points in detail how the files are stored in Autodesk construction Cloud?

@VijayKumbhoje Can you share API format of the file stored in Autodesk construction Cloud and add it question ?

Thanks for response, The question I asked is little about feasibility so @RithwikBojja I am yet to put hands on it. On Autodesk construction Cloud (ACC ) we have stored CAD, Revit files and want to use AZ Copy to move it to Azure Storage. I knew that we can do it from on-premise to Azure Storage or from one account to another account. But will it work with ACC?

@VijayKumbhoje Could you please edit the question and it there and not in comment?

@Venkatesan I have updated my question with more details, Thanks

From your script, I'd say if you download everything to a local drive and then use az copy to upload it, it will properly work without an issue. If that is your approach?

@JulianHüppauff We planning to use Azure function to do that, So no involvement of local drives it will be serverless operation.

Are you planning a one time operation or a continued one?

As of now with timer function we may run it with specific schedule

@VijayKumbhoje Check the below answer, you can use the same code in your function code.


Can we use AZCopy to transfer files from Autodesk construction Cloud to Azure Storage?

According to this Document,
AzCopy is CLI tool specifically designed for transferring data to and from Azure Storage accounts, including Blob Storage, File Storage, and on-premise to Azure Storage.
However, AzCopy does not natively support third-party APIs or platforms like Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC).
I would suggest that you can convert the data into stream from Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC) and upload using Azure blob Storage SDK using C#.
Code:

var fileDownloadUrl = "Your file URL from the Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC)";
using var fileResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(fileDownloadUrl);
fileResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

using var fileStream = await fileResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
string fileName = "signature.jpg"; // The name of the file to transfer
string azureBlobConnectionString = "your-azure-blob-connection-string";
string containerName = "your-container-name";

// Upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
var blobClient = new BlobClient(azureBlobConnectionString, containerName, fileName);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);

Reference:
Upload a blob with .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
